# Duplicate vs Existed

Tags: java, methods, naming-conventions, naming

Let say I would like to insert a product. 
However, before inserting it I need to check if its name already existed in a table product.

what is the suitable method's name? I am a bit confused about that.

```
isDuplicatedName(String _name)

isExistedName(String _name)
```

Sorry in advance if there are grammar errors. Thank you.

Comment: `hasName` or `containsName`. Only the caller knows that it wants to insert this name again, which is what makes it a duplicate. The method just checks whether the name does already exist.

Answer (score 2):

According to **Elegant Objects (Volume 1): Yegor Bugayenko**, in general, There are two types of methods.

1. **Builder methods**

   These methods build something and return a new object.

   > Their names must be a noun.

   ```
   Student student (Long id);
   List<Car> cars ();
   Long salary(Long id);
   ```
2. **Manipulator methods**

   These methods always make a modification to data and return nothing.(always return **void**)

   > Their names must be a verb.

   ```
   void save(Student student);
   void print(String name);
   void delete (Long id);
   void persist(Student student);
   ```

> **So Builders build and manipulators manipulate**

There is a little exception for methods that return **boolean**.
For this type of method, It's better to use adjective for naming.

```
   boolean empty();
   boolean existent(Long id);
```

I would recommend you to use an adjective for your method naming and don't use ***"is"*** in your naming.

**Names of your method could be:**

```
boolean productExistent(String name);
boolean productNameExistent(String name);
boolean nameExistent(String name);
boolean existent(String name);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase and with the first letter of each internal word capitalised.  [ref.code-conventions-135099](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Based on this you may be using `isDuplicate()` or `isExisting()` or `isDuplicatedName()` or `isExistingName()`

Answer (score 0):

.isDuplicated(_name) sounds like you ALREADY have more then one entity with given name.
.isExist(_name) returns true > then 0.

These methods for different cases.